# Making dll change form properties

Tags: c#, dll

I have an dll with the following method:

```
  public void SetFormProperties(){
      frm.Size = new Size(20,20);
      ...
  }
```

The method will set various properties and attach events to form. What is the best way to pass form so the method can access the properties so that when the form appears, it instantly inherits the properties set by method?

EDIT: Sorry, I didnt make my question clear. Can I make it so that I add SetFormProperties() into form_Load() Event and make it apply the properties without me passing the form reference? Thanks!

Comment: How should we know? Where does `frm` come from?

Comment: Based on the information you've given us, I'd say: _As a parameter_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless this is a trick question, you can pass the `frm` instance in after you create it:

```
public void SetFormProperties(Form frm){
    frm.Size = new Size(20,20);
    ...
}
```

so when you create it:

```
var frm = new Form1();
SetFormProperties(frm);
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question. Can I set the variables without passing the form. Like use something like parent.backColor?

Comment: @user1192403: If `SetFormProperties()` exists in the base class (e.g. you're not using the `Form` class as your base but you've created your own that bases `Form`) or `SetFormProperties()` exists on the form itself, then you wouldn't need to send in the reference because you could leverage `this.Size`.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you provided will not work. You need to return the new size or pass in the reference to the form object.

```
 public void SetFormProperties(Form form){
      fprm.Size = new Size(20,20);
  }

SetFormPropertoes(form);
```

OR

```
 public Size GetFormSize(){
      return new Size(20,20);
  }

from.Size = GetFormSize();
```